# Difference Between TimeZoneInfo ConvertTimeFromUtc and ConvertTime

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I am converting a project from .Net 4.5 to PCL targeting the .NetStandard 1.6 and it looks like `TimeZoneInfo` doesn't have the method `ConvertTimeFromUtc`.   If the time going in has its type set to UTC is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a DateTime to the local time you can use this :

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime localDateTime = new DateTime(utcDateTime.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
localDateTime = localDateTime.ToLocalTime();
```